# How do i replace multiple resource placeholder in asp.net view?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, resources, resx

I have resource as like `"This fruit is {0} color, and have stock of {1}."` How do replace `{0} and {1}`  with `red and 5` in MVC view ?

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I found myself. `string.Format(Resourcekey,"red",5)`